# Correction of mutliple paired samples t-test

Tags: t-test, multiple-comparisons, paired-comparisons

In one group of subjects I have four parameters (for e.g. A, B, C, D) measured in two conditions. I want to know whether these 4 parameters differ between the conditions by doing paired samples t-tests. Do I have to apply a correction for the level of significance since I am doing the test 4 times?

Comment: Can you say something about the nature of these parameters? From a theoretical standpoint are they considered to be unrelated to each other, or are the 4 measures of a similar construct?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, yes. The problem of repeated testing is not extreme in this case, but it would still be prudent. Best to present both corrected (*eg* Bonferroni)  and uncorrected p-values. You could also do a repeated measures ANOVA or express you response as pre-to-post difference and do a one-way ANOVA. But you are saying "in one group if subjects" - are there multiple groups as well?